# Which key combination would allow me to pass parameters to kernel during boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I want to pass some parameters like the runlevel, nomodeset to kernel during the booting process.

Which  key combination would allow me to pass the parameters to the kernel, in redhat it used to just an arrow key to get to the kernel options.

I had tried pressing and holding the shift key during the boot process to go the kernel options according to other posts but they didn't seem to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hold shift to get to the grub menu, then select the entry you want using `up` and `down`, then hit `e` to the edit mode. It has instructions after that on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: i tried with the shift key, but it ain't working for me. Is there any other key which can get me there?

Comment: left shift. You might have to turn on usb keyboard in your BIOS if you are using a usb keyboard, or you can try to find a PS/2 keyboard (if your motherboard has that port, most do), which always work.

Comment: try pressing the shift key repeatedly after the BIOS screen, if you press and hold it too quickly or slowly it will miss the key press. @Ankit  this causes keyboard buffer overruns on some computers so it may not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to bring up the GRUB menu then <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the highlighted kernel choice.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the answer above. Can you add anything else?